# Discord.js v13 - Extract Image Embed attached in Message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am writing a function that returns an Image Embed from a Message. I mean, Image from MessageEmbed.

> **The thing:** Discord resolves the Image URL and returns an Image Embed object instead (can be found using `message.embeds` property).

[**Here's an example image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOzfs.jpg)

And here is the main problem:

> When you are trying to access in `embeds` property from Message Object, will get an empty Array like this: `[]`. But accessing again will get the expected result. `[ [MessageEmbed] ]` An ImageEmbed.

The problem with this is **Discord** takes some time to resolve the URL and displays into Message as Attachment, and dont want to use the `setTimeout` function to wait it. Because if the message contains multiple image URLs this will take more time.
*Well...* trying to access in `embeds` property after that operation will not work properly because returns again... an empty array.

So looking the `messageUpdate` event i found that emits the same Message with the Image URL resolved in `embeds` property. So i make this code:

```
async function getImageEmbeds(message) {
   // Access into Client to listen the messageUpdate event.
   const { client } = message;
   const collectedImages = new Array();

   // Waits the event emittion
   await new Promise((resolve) => {
      function fnListener(oldmsg, newmsg) {
         if (message.id !== newmsg.id) return;
         const imageEmbeds = newmsg.embeds.filter(embed => embed.thumbnail !== null).map(embed => embed.thumbnail);
         collectedImages.push(...imageEmbeds);
       
         client.removeListener("messageUpdate", fnListener);
         // Ends this promise.
         resolve(true);
      }
      client.on("messageUpdate", fnListener);
   })

   return collectedImages;
}
```

This code works as expected (Waits the Image URL resolving that will be emitted in `messageUpdate` event and returns an Array with the Image Embed resolved). But there's a new problem, The function will wait indefinitely if the message doesn't have an Image URL.

- How i can tell to the function if the message has an unresolved Image URL?

Any suggestions that can solve this problem?

Comment: Discord.js has a concept of Collectors, maybe you can try to integrate your code in one of them: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collector

Comment: You could use RegExp to check for an image URL in the message content.